# How to find if data is fetched from url in deck gl

Tags: reactjs, url, mapbox-gl-js, layer

I want lo load data from a url, to my geojsonlayer

I passed the url to the data prop, and it is appearing on the map.

But I want to know the features that are present on my layer..

How do I do it.

Answer (score 1):

While creating the layer, add a method `onDataLoad`, it takes a callback as parameter and returns the data of that layer

Comment: How to use the onDataLoad prop can you just show an example. Is this props is supported for all layer types or only for mvt layer

Comment: onHover: (info: EventData) => {
   /* code */
},
onDataLoad: (data: RootObject) => {
      /* your code goes here */
}